# MapView user location settled down

Tags: swift, xcode

So I am creating an app that uses the user location. On the map, when the user opens the app, the User Location usually starts really far away from my actual location. Obviously after a couple seconds though, the dot hones in on my location and stops. But not before slowly crossing the map. Is there a way to disable user interaction in the mapview till the users location is stabilized. Or if that is not possible, is there a way to make the user location not animate slowly across the screen, and just jump.

Answer (score 0):

Interfering with the default animation might be tricky. Controlling user interaction is relatively simple. You could enable interaction only after some locational stability condition has been reached.

For instance you could disable interaction with the relevant fields or buttons in your viewDidLoad:

```
myTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Then, run a function to monitor the location for stability. This could be a loop every half second or so:

```
repeat {
  wait 0.5 seconds
  increment loop count
  get the current location
  calculate the distance between current and previous locations, ∆x
  store current location
  }
while |∆x| > arbitrary distance precision AND loop count < 10

myTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```